# package does not exist error!

Tags: java, import, package

I have a directory structure like `com/example/web` under the root directory which contains a java file `Bear.java`. I have another java file `BearExtra.java` in directory structure `com/example/model` in same root directory as above. I am calling a method in `BearExtra.java` from `Bear.java` and  I am getting the error that the package does not exist.

I have imported `com.example.model` package in my java file. Can give me some advice?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have?

Comment: Did the compiler really say `package does not exist error!!` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This works:

### com/example/model/BearExtra.java

```
package com.example.model;

public class BearExtra {
  public static void go() {
    System.out.println("Yay, it works!");
  } 
}
```

### com/example/web/Bear.java

```
package com.example.web;

import com.example.model.*;

public class Bear {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BearExtra.go();
  }
}
```

Now, to compile and run these classes, go to the directory where you can "see" the `com` folder and do:

### *nix/MacOS

```
javac -cp . com/example/model/*.java com/example/web/*.java
java -cp . com.example.web.Bear
```

### Windows

```
javac -cp . com\example\model\*.java com\example\web\*.java
java -cp . com.example.web.Bear
```

and the following is being printed to the console:

```
Yay, it works!
```

Comment: for others compiling on terminal make sure your javac is in the parent most directory. an example: http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/using-javac-and-java-commands-to-compile-and-launch-java-programs/ This answer had the solution present. I wanted to add emphasis on this scenerio.

Answer (score -1):

Did you specify the 'package' in your class files?

Bear.java

```
package com.example.web;

import com.example.model.*;

class Bear { ...
```

BearExtra.java

```
package com.example.model;

public class BearExtra { ...
```

Comment: Is the BearExtra class public?

Comment: Further code / compiler output is required. You need to make the question information more detailed.

Comment: Why don't you use any of the IDE's available ? IDE will simplify the job of compiling and importing the right packages.

Comment: @Rakesh, I take it that's not aimed at me, so better to post against the question, no?  (I'm using Eclipse...)  Plus it is best to understand what the IDE is doing.