# Package errors in Java

Tags: java

When I am trying to compile class which having package statement the folder is not created with package name and its classes? Currently I am trying to compile this on windows7 64bit OS from Guest account?

```
package Sample;

class Sample
{
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Sample Example for Package");
    }
}
```

compilation statement:

```
javac Sample.java
```

Comment: if you are using javac from command prompt, It will not create a package folder. You yourself will have to create one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [package does not exist error!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665420/package-does-not-exist-error)

Comment: Try to avoid same package and class names. Also, if you are using an IDE, creating package will create directories too but for case of normal text editors, you will have to create directories manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Sample.java` file is in `D:\codes\` go inside that folder using command prompt and issue this command,

`javac -d D:\codes\ Sample.java`

this will create packages and put your `.class` files in it.

Comment: Is there compulsory that we need to specify the path after '-d' when we are compiling from same folder like D:\codes\

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment first, If you are compiling from D:\codes\ you can use `.` after `-d` like this `javac -d . Sample.java`