# Java package and directories

Tags: java, package

It may be a similar to this question : [package does not exist error!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665420/package-does-not-exist-error)
but I don't understand how to manage it.

I try to follow this lesson (in French sorry) https://openclassrooms.com/courses/les-tests-unitaires-en-java

and so I have the following tree : 
Garage/test/XXXTest.java, Garage/main/impl/XXX.java, Garage/main/inter/XXX.java

In test I have this code (GPSTest.Java)

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

import main.impl.GPS;

public class GPSTest
{
    @Test
    public final void GPSTest() {
        GPS gps = new GPS();
        double prix = gps.getPrix();
        assertTrue("Test prix GPS", prix == 113.5);
    }
}
```

and in main/impl I have this one (GPS.java)

```
package main.impl; 

import main.inter.Option;

public class GPS implements Option
{
    public double getPrix()
    {
        return 113.5;
    }
}
```

and in main/inter I have (Option.java)

```
package main.inter;

public interface Option 
{
    public double getPrix();
}
```

When I try to compile (I'm in Garage)

```
javac -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\junit-4.10.jar" test\GPSTest.java
```

I have this error

```
test\GPSTest.java:6: error: package main.impl does not exist
import main.impl.GPS;
```

Do I need to add Garage in the package name ? In the lesson (linked above) it's the same architecture and the same package name... But they use Eclipse, so maybe there are some differences (I use the command line)

---

EDIT 
If I remove the test part it works :
test\TestGPS.java

```
package test;

/*import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;*/

import main.impl.GPS;

public class GPSTest
{
   // @Test
    public final void GPSTest() {
        GPS gps = new GPS();
        double prix = gps.getPrix();
        //assertTrue("Test prix GPS", prix == 113.5);
        System.out.println(prix);
    }
}
```

With the following command doesn't give error... So I suppose the problem is with the classpath, but how can I fix it ?

```
javac test\GPSTest.java
```

Comment: `import main.Main` does not appear in any of the code you posted; neither does `class Main`; and you don't have any classes in `package main`. What's the real code?

Comment: @EJP Oups. I tested some things and I forgot to retry on the right code.
I edited the post, the error is `test\GPSTest.java:6: error: package main.impl does not exist
import main.impl.GPS;`

Comment: So does `main/impl/GPS.java` exist?

Comment: @EJP Yes, in Garage : Garage/main/impl/GPS.java
(I'm not on the right computer so I cant' show you... Maybe there is a difference I don't see, but I've checked many times)

Comment: @EJP I confirm, `main\impl\GPS.java` exists

Comment: And you are in the directory `Garage` when you compile? such that `main` is a subdirectory of the current directory, and `impl` a subdirectory of that?

Comment: @EJP Exact main and test are in Garage

Comment: @EJP some news : if I remove all the things about testing, it works... I put the informations in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the clathpass. I had to add the current file to the path with `.;` before the rest of the path:

```
javac -cp .;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\junit-4.10.jar" test\GPSTest.java
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to add Garage in the package name

No, but you need to be in the directory `Garage` when you compile, such that you are at the head of the following directory tree:

```
main
main/impl
main/impl/GPS.java
main/inter
main/inter/Option.java
test
test/GPSTest.java
```

Comment: But I am in Garage and I have this tree